# 上网 vs 网上 word order

Tags: word-order

I've seen some sentences, and some of them use `上网`:

```
通过上网聊天，我认识了很多新朋友

Through online chat, I meet many new friends
```

whereas for another case, it uses `网上`:

```
网上购物是最流行的生活方式

Online shopping is the most popular lifestyle.
```

In both sentences, they mean as "online". But I'm a bit confused on the word order, when should we use `上网` and when should we use `网上`?

Comment: 通过上网 "by going onto the web" (上 functions as verb) , 网上 "on the web" (functions as postposition (preposition)),

Comment: Are you familiar with 楼上 vs 上楼? Same idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

上网 is a Verb Object construction internally ("ascend net" = to get on the web). 上网购物 is a Serial Verb construction: first action 上网, second action 购物. Both actions are equal, not subordinate/main, as both are needed. "Serial" because they are chronological (need to 上网 first, before you can 购物, another Verb Object construction internally). A similar construction: 上车买票 "ascend vehicle buy voucher" = get on the bus/tram/train and buy the ticket).

网上 is an Adverb (answers the question "where": "where buy things?" --> 网上购物 "net on buy thing" = to shop online).  Can be an Adjective (what kind of shopping? online shopping).

Answer (score 3):

上网 is used when someone is doing the action of going online. 
网上 (or sometimes 网路上）means online / on the web.

For instance, of the two examples you provided, you could use 网上 or 上网 under different circumstances.

> 通过上网聊天，我认识了很多新朋友

You could use "网上" to express a similar meaning:

> 我在网上认识了很多朋友。

And

> 网上购物是最流行的生活方式

You could use "上网" to express a similar meaning

> 很多人喜欢上网买东西。

Hope this helps clear things up! :)

Answer (score 0):

上网 and 网上 are interchangable in the two cases but not all, the meanings are similar but different in Chinese. 上网 literally means **go to the internet** in Chinglish, while 网上 literally means **on the internet**. The word **上** in **上 + somewhere** structure is a verb like that **to go** in English, generally means **go to** or **get on**, like 上网, 上车, 上楼, 上学, 上课. The word **上** in **somewhere + 上** structure is a preposition like that **on** or **upon** in English, like 网上, 车上, 楼上, 地上, 桌上.

Answer (score 0):

上网==上+网，here 上 is a verb, meaning surf, go on

网上==(在)+网+上，here 在...上 means on, a preposition. But in most time, 在 is dropped off. In the same way, 桌上==在桌上， 纸上==在纸上,here 上 after nouns is the preposition.

Moreover, 线下==(在)线下，碗里==（在）碗里，屋外==(在)屋外

Answer (score 0):

上网, literally "to get on the internet" [上=(verb)to get on something, 网=(noun)internet], means to surf on the internet.

网上, literally "on the internet" [网=(noun)internet, -上=(postposition)on something], means to be online.

上网聊天 = to use the internet in order to chat.

网上聊天 = to chat online